# Removing a SheduledAction with aws cli

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I remove a scheduled action with the AWS CLI?

I can already create them with:

> aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name $myenv
>   --option-settings file://my.json

my.json:

> [ { "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:scheduledaction", "OptionName":
>   "MinSize", "Value": "1", "ResourceName": "MyResource" } ... ]

Now I would like to remove MyResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has to be used:

> aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name $myenv --options-to-remove file://delete.json

Now the trick is that you have to list `all` of the properties (MinSize, MaxSize, Suspended, ...) you have set to the resource or else a misleading error is raised.